# Akka : the proper use of `ask` pattern?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, future

I'm trying to grok `Futures` and ask pattern in akka.

So, I make two actors, and one asking another to send him back a message. Well, according to akka's `Futures` documentation, actor should *ask*(`?`) for message and it shall give him a `Future` instanse. Then actor should block (using `Await`) to get `Future` results.

Well, I never get my future done. Why is that?

Code is:

```
package head_thrash

import akka.actor._
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("actors")

  val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "node_1")
  val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "node_2")

  actor2 ! "ping_other"

  system.awaitTermination()

  Console.println("Bye!")
}

class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import akka.pattern.ask

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(100.days)

  def receive = {
    case "ping_other" => {
      val selection = context.actorSelection("../node_1")
      log.info("Sending ping to node_1")
      val result = Await.result(selection ? "ping", Duration.Inf) // <-- Blocks here forever!
      log.info("Got result " + result)
    }
    case "ping" => {
      log.info("Sending back pong!")
      sender ! "pong"
    }
  }
}
```

If I change `Duration.Inf` to `5.seconds`, then actor waits 5 seconds, tells that my future is *Timeouted* (by throwing `TimeoutException`), and then other actor finally replies with needed message. So, no async happens. Why? :-(

How should I properly implement that pattern? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The official Akka [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html) says that Await.result will cause the current thread to block and wait for the Actor to 'complete' the Future with it's reply.

It is strange that your code blocks there forever, do you have only one thread for all your application?

Anyway I guess a more "idiomatic" way to code it would be to use a callback on the future success.

```
def receive = {
    case "ping_other" => {
      val selection = context.actorSelection("../node_1")
      log.info("Sending ping to node_1")
      val future: Future[String] = ask(selection, "ping").mapTo[String]
      future.onSuccess { 
         case result : String ⇒ log.info("Got result " + result)
      }
    }
...
```

Comment: Yay, that worked! Seems like app is really using just one thread. That's very confusing.

Comment: I needed to add some import to make your method work: ```import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global```

Comment: An Akka app is not single threaded. The way it works is that actors process mailbox messages on a thread from a threadpool and then release that thread once the message is processed. That means if you block in a receive, that thread is blocked and the actor won't process any more messages. You should therefore avoid blocking.

Comment: @justinhj Agree. Simply: this is a bad example!

Comment: More "idiomatic" way - use `pipe` to send the result of a Future to an Actor

Answer (score 5):

Two reasons why that doesn't work.

First, "node_1" asks itself and the "ping" will not be processed because it is blocking in waiting for the ask.

Also, there is a shortcoming of actorSelection for relative paths ("../node_1"). It is processed with message passing, and since your actor is blocking it cannot process any other message. This has been improved in upcoming 2.3 version of Akka, but you should avoid blocking anyway.

Comment: _First, "node_1" asks itself_ - why is that? I sent `ping_other` message to node_2, which selected node_1, and sent `ping` to node_1, so, it does not seem to me that node_1 is asking itself. Or did I miss something?